# Is there a way to have different cell values under a dropdown in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In the example below we see athletes and competitions.

[image]

There are multiple competitions and many athletes ,
The above works but there are so many athletes and the names span all the way to the right and is hard to read. 
 I can create a dropdown for the athlete names (so I only have one column) but that doesnt solve the problem which is that under the dropdown every athlete should be able to have different competitions that they might be going to (different values) .

[dropdown list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4V49.png)

So if I use the dropdown how can I make all the values below dependant to it but dynamic (so an athlete can enter what they want but when the next athlete selects their name they can start over ) or if this is not possible what is a good way to do this ?

Comment: I really can't tell what you want from your description.  But perhaps an internet search for "dependent dropdowns" will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered only creating two columns?:

(1) A pull down list of each event with the location and date, and

(2) A pull down list with each athlete's name

This would allow each person to sign up for an event and add their name on each line. Then, if you need a "sub list" for each event, you can go back at the end of the sign-up period and sort the entire table by the event column.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put all your data in a sheet (call it DATA)
2. Create another sheet and copy columns Day to Location with all data (call it ATHLETES)
3. On ATHLETES sheet cell E1 add a data validation with all names from sheet DATA.
4. Use change event on sheet ATHLETES cell E1.
5. If cell E1 value change trigger the event to:
   Clear the range of column E
   Get the value of cell E1
   Using FIND method to find which column in sheet DATA 
   has the specific athlete name and copy paste the data to 
   ATHLETES sheet.